# Navigation Bar In Mobile Version

Tags: jquery, html, css

When i want to use the mobile version (make the browser window smaller) and when i click on the hamburger menu when the list is in hide situation after you make the window bigger the navigation bar going to disappear at all. And as you know this is a problem. How can i fix it?!

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function () {

            jQuery(".menu-trigger").click(function () {

                jQuery(".nav").slideToggle(400, function () {
                    jQuery(this).toggleClass("nav-expended").css('display')
                });

            });

        });
```

```css
body {
    background-color:#e8e2e2;
}
.nav {
    position: relative;
    list-style: none;
    width: 100%;
    height: 40px;
    z-index: 100;
    vertical-align: top;
    margin: 0 auto;
}
ul {
    list-style: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}
a {
    display:block;
    width: 250px;
    color:white;
    text-decoration:none;
    height:100%;
    text-align:center;
    z-index:100;
   font: bold 17px/40px arial, sans-serif;
   background-color:teal;
}
li {
    display: inline;
    float: left;
}
a:hover {
       border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
}
.nav ul li:hover ul{
    display: block;
}
.nav ul ul {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
    background-color:black;
}
li:hover > a {
  background: #222222;
}
li a:hover {
  background: #3a3a3a;
}
.nav ul ul li {
    display: block;
}
.nav ul ul li {
    display: block;
}

.menu-trigger {
    display:none;
}

div.nav-menu {
    display:none;
}

div.nav-expended {
    display:block;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1050px) {
    div.nav ul li {
        float: none;
        border-bottom: 2px solid black;
    }

        div.nav ul li::after last-child {
            border-bottom: none;
        }
    .menu-trigger {
        display:block;
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="#" style="font-size:20px;" class="menu-trigger"><b>&#9776;</b></a>

    <div class="nav">
     <div id="nav_wrapper">
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li><li>
            <a href="#">About</a></li><li>
            <a href="#">Contact Us</a></li><li>
            <a href="#">Social</a>
                <ul style="margin-right:600px;">
                    <li><a href="#">YouTube</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Twitter</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Facebook</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
     </div>
   </div>
```

Comment: Post a jsFiddle or something for us to look at.

Comment: You gotta show us *something*. Can you host it live somewhere? I really don't think anybody is going to be able to answer you just looking at your code.

Comment: You can make a file of that right?! @philtune

Comment: The animation of the clicking on the hamburger menu doesn't work! [link](http://jsfiddle.net/b0u6q76m/embedded/result/) @philtune

Comment: Does  the code in `JavaScript.js` make it work? You have to embed all resources that make your code work.

Comment: I did! But I think you can use note pad or something to just copying code in it and run it. Right?! @philtune

Comment: Hey, the console is your friend here. Click F12 and click "Console" tab to see all the errors you're getting. You need to include whatever code and resources that are relevant. If they're not relevant to your issue then remove them... we need to see minimal viable code: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: BTW, don't ask others to do what you can do yourself (eg, copy/paste your code into a file... that's what Snippets are for). But to help you out, I edited your post to include a Snippet. The hamburger seems to work in that example.

Comment: ooo! i didn't know anything about Snippet actually! sorry for that. but actually that didn't work. I have the same problem that i had! @philtune

Comment: omg! it didn't work again :( @philtune

Answer (score 1):

Inside your media query, you need to make the nav always visible when the page is at the larger size

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1050px) {
    div.nav {
        display: block !important;
    }

}
```